# Single use triggers, is there any reason to delete them?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I've been using triggers for a while now and only just learned about time triggers that do not repeat.

Example:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("MyFunction")
.timeBased()
.at(new Date((new Date()).getTime()+1000*60*2))
.create();
```

vs

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("MyFunction")
.timeBased()
.everyDays(1)
.create();
```

Are there any cautions about using the first type of trigger? Do I need to delete them for any reason? I think they would make my current script cleaner but I don't want to realize later i've completely broken something by switching from my current, ugly "make a trigger for 10 minutes from now" "delete all triggers at the start of the function" cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that we're capped at a max of 20 triggers per project (see [Current Limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) section on Quotas page), you may want to delete one-time triggers for projects where you have to manage a lot of triggers.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!